# Why can't I see wieght colors unless I use the numpad [ / ] key?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

Why can't I see weight colors unless I use <kbd>`/`</kbd> key? It seems I can only see the weight colors when the object is isolated but that isn't always practical. How can it work with all items in view?

Comment: Have you switched to weight paint mode (instead of object or edit mode)?

Answer (score 1):

You can barely see weight paint colors while in the Material shading mode if the shape is not in *Local View*, you have to switch shading mode to Solid.

I was going to delete this post but others have asked before why they can't see weight paint colors.

Comment: Can't confirm that behaviour, also couldn't get the reason to preview weight paint in Material shading mode.